# How to keep socket open when a react native app is in background?

Tags: react-native, socket.io

Is there any way to keep the same socket open when the app is running in the background? The connection gets disconnected a few seconds after stepping out of the app like going to the home screen.

I'm using Socket.io btw.

Thanks.